# Settings Transfer

Tags: file, firefox, file-transfer

I have numerous profiles, and I have certain ones used to manually transfer updated files to the others.

The one thing I'm not sure about is browser settings transfer.  Because some these profiles have different addons, I don't want the addons settings transferred, just the browser settings.

Can this simply be done with settings folder?

I'm looking for advice before I try.